# Google Sheets - Formula to remove data to the left of `:`

Tags: google-sheets

Ive got a bunch of values like this :

`one: 1; | two: 2; | three: 3;`

(each value is in its own cell eg. `one: 1;`

For each value i want to remove the `:` and everything to the left of the `:` so i would have

`1; | 2; | 3;`

Is this possible to do with a formula in Google Sheets ? Ive seen lots of ways to do it online with Excel using Excel's inbuilt GUI features, but ive not seen a solution using formulas that would work in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [**REGEXEXTRACT() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en#null):

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"[^:]*")`

The meaning of the formula is simple - take all the left symbols, except for the colon.

To get the right part of the string, after the colon - just add a dollar sign **$** at the end of the regular_expression

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^:]*$")`

This feature is available in Google Sheets, but not in most other spreadsheets. Therefore, if you are looking for a universal solution that will work in Google spreadsheets, Excel and Calc, then build a "traditional" formula - find the position of the colon using the [**FIND() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en#null), cut off the left side of the original string with [**LEFT()**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en#null). Since it may happen that there is no colon in the source cell, wrap the formula in the [**IFERROR() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en#null)

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1),A1)`

To get the right side of a string, the formula might be:

`=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1)),A1)`

or

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),A1)`

In addition, you can use other string processing tricks, for example:

`=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,":"),0,2)`

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*:"),"")` etc.

Comment: thanks, ive read the google sheet docs, but im not sure if i understand regular expressions, im going to read up about them in more detail, but in the meantime do you know how to ` remove the : and everything to the LEFT of the :` currently your example snippet ` removes the : and everything to the RIGHT of the :`

Comment: Of course I know - just add dollar sign **$**  at the end - `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[^:]*$")`